# Not getting a return object from a MySQL query in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm making a logging system in NodeJS with MySQL DB. First I do the connection like this:

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'dbuser',
  password : 'dbpass',
  database : 'dbname',
  port     : 3306,
  multipleStatements : true
});
```

Then when I do a query to get users data I do the following query.

```
var user;
con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', email, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
       user = rows[0];
    }
});
```

But when I finally compare any of the fields of the user returned I get an error:

```
if (tools.hashPassword(password) == user.hash) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", email, function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        if (!rows.length) {
            throw new Error("User not found");
        }
        const user = rows[0];
        if (tools.hashPassword(password) == user.hash) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you are getting the result, but it is asynchronous. Therefore at the time you check for user's property `hash`, the object itself has not loaded yet. You should put your comparison in the callback like this:

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', email, function(err, rows) {
  if (err) throw err;
  else {
     if (tools.hashPassword(password) === rows[0].hash) {
        // Do stuff
     }
  }
});

// This stuff happens usually BEFORE the query's callback,
// due to Node.js asynchronous nature
```